# Spark SQL Character Encoding Issues

Tags: python-2.7, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm reading in an RDD/DF like so:

```
testRDD=sc.textFile('s3n://sample.txt')\.map(lambda x: x.split('|')).map(lambda x: Row(event_date=x[0])).cache()

testDF = sqlContext.createDataFrame(testRDD)
testDF.registerTempTable("testDF")
```

The RDD returns data that looks fine:

```
for i in testRDD.take(1):
    print(i)

Row(event_date=u'2016-04-01 00:00:17')
```

But the DF comes up with some encoding issues where the first several characters are missing and the string ends in a bunch of encoded bytes:

```
for i in testDF.take(1):
    print(i) 

Row(event_date=u'01 00:00:17\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x05\x00\x00')
```

Any ideas where I'm going wrong? I've tried using decode('utf-8') on the incoming string with no luck.